# Formal proof of $f(n) = \Theta(f(n/2))$

Tags: limits, functions, asymptotics

Is $f(n) = \Theta(f(n/2))$?

If I take $f = 2^n$, then whatever value I choose for the constant c, 
$$2^n \geq c \cdot {2^{n/2}}$$

there exists a value of n, such that $2^n$ is bigger.

How can I show that there is no limit on how large $2^{n/2}$ can be, so that $2^n \neq \Theta(2^{n/2}) $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can proceed as follows: for $f$ defined by $f(n)=2^{n}$, we have $f(n/2) = \sqrt{f(n)}$ for every $n\geq 0$, and therefore
$$
\frac{f(n)}{f(n/2)} = \sqrt{f(n)} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty
$$
However, $f(n) = O(f(n/2))$ would require the ratio to be bounded, namely
$$
\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{f(n/2)} < \infty\,.
$$